URL encoding with semicolons (;) in Java using UriComponentsBuilder
I’m working on encoding semicolons (;) in URL query parameters using Java. The semicolons need to be encoded as %3B, but I'm running into an issue where they are either get double-encoded as %253B or not encoding at all.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
var rawSemicolon = String.join(";",
    Arrays.stream(endpoints)
            .map(MyEndpointObject::toString)
            .toArray(String[]::new));

System.out.println(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/foo/bar")
    .queryParam("query1", rawSemicolon)
    .queryParam("query2", URLEncoder.encode(rawSemicolon, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    .build().toUri());

System.out.println(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/foo/bar")
    .queryParam("query1", rawSemicolon)
    .queryParam("query2", URLEncoder.encode(rawSemicolon, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    .build(false).toUri());

var semicolonEncoded = String.join("%3B",
    Arrays.stream(endpoints)
            .map(VehicleDataEndpoint::toString)
            .toArray(String[]::new));

System.out.println(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/foo/bar")
    .queryParam("query1", semicolonEncoded)
    .queryParam("query2", URLEncoder.encode(semicolonEncoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    .build().toUri());

System.out.println(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/foo/bar")
    .queryParam("query1", semicolonEncoded)
    .queryParam("query2", URLEncoder.encode(semicolonEncoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    .build(false).toUri());

Output:
/foo/bar?query1=endpoint1;endpoint2&query2=endpoint1%253Bendpoint2
/foo/bar?query1=endpoint1;endpoint2&query2=endpoint1%253Bendpoint2
/foo/bar?query1=endpoint1%253Bendpoint2&query2=endpoint1%25253Bendpoint2
/foo/bar?query1=endpoint1%253Bendpoint2&query2=endpoint1%25253Bendpoint2


Why do you want that? ; is perfectly legal character in url. No wonder encoder don't let you do it.

I know, but the API I am consuming doesn’t work with ; In postman it only works with %3B and not with ; Also, I cannot change this third-party API

In that case you need to implement your own UriComponentsBuilder.

URIComponentsBuilder contains a method build(boolean), where the parameter indicates whether the URI components are already encoded. So, is encoding the components manually and then using build(true) at the end an option?
For example, the following code:
        var rawSemicolon = "endpoint1;endpoint2";

        System.out.println(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/foo/bar")
                .queryParam("query1", rawSemicolon)
                .queryParam("query2", URLEncoder.encode(rawSemicolon, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .build(true).toUri());

displays the following:
/foo/bar?query1=endpoint1;endpoint2&query2=endpoint1%3Bendpoint2

The value for query2 appears to be what you want, even if the value for
query1 might not be.

The URL spec says that ; does not need to be encoded in a query part.  Thus
/foo/bar?query1=endpoint1;endpoint2

is totally valid according to the spec.  Furthermore
/foo/bar?query1=endpoint1%3Bendpoint2

should mean exactly the same thing as the previous ... assuming that the receiver is handling it correctly according to the URL spec.
The problemis that the key-value query syntax "a=b;c=d" is not part of the URL specification.  It is merely a (widely used) convention.
Thus, when (as I understand it) you want to use the ; as a data character in the value of a KV pair (i.e. "a=x;y;b=z") you are breaking the convention.  And percent encoding the ; (technically) won't remedy this.  (Or if it does it will be because the software handling the URL is not decoding it correctly.)
The CORRECT way to handle this is to design a custom syntax for encoding the information in your query strings.  For example, use a , instead of a ; like this:
/foo/bar?query1=endpoint1,endpoint2;query2=...

I know ... that's probably not what you want to do.  (Because ... reasons.)  But if you fix this now you will avoid future problems with this API you are designing.

If this is an existing API that someone else designed and you have to deal with, you may need to resort to hacky things to encode the query parameters in the way that this poorly designed API expects.  For example, see Luke Woodward's answer.

(I might not be understanding, but semicolon is a bit unusual, and maybe treated weird.)
The semicolon ; is special as it sometimes is (ab)used to write URLs like:
https://www.wiki.net/info;param=42

This makes the first ; as something not to URL encode, and following semicolons to be URL encoded. I hope this is not the case here.
Unlikely though that UriComponentsBuilder uses some special treatment of semicolons.
Now Spring's UriComponentsBuilder is a class to provide URL encoding for the parameter values, and leave the query string and parameter fringes untouched.
So one should not need to URL encode oneself. However Spring generalizes by allowing to leave the URL encoding nevertheless to you. That is done by a boolean parameter.
However that defies the entire reason for this class.
Hence either do the URL encoding of the parameter values yourself with URLEncoder and do not use UriComponentsBuilder. Or you find a working solution using UriComponentsBuilder in some other answer.
